# how to change value "bool(true)" after submit form

Tags: php, symfony1

form.php

```
  <?php echo form_tag('branchOfficialMTL/UpdateMyAddressemail', array('id' => 'person_edit')); ?>

   <?php if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="PUT" />
<?php endif; ?>
  <table>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields() ?>        
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
   </form>
```

- After submit form i found :-

  var_dump($request->isMethod('post'));die;
- result :-  bool(false)
- So I need result bool(true)
- what would i do for result bool(true)

Comment: That's because you're not submitting the request as `POST`, it's `GET` instead.

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can help you.

Comment: Provide the html form code part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to modify your form to be something like `<form method="post" action="...">...</form>`

AND You need to update this piece of code as well:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="PUT" />
```

into

```
<input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="POST" />
```

Comment: we have changed it but problem is not resolve same result found

Comment: You are setting PUT method here `<input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="PUT" />`, Change this into `<input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="POST" />`

Comment: Please, mark this answer as helpful, so others will know that it helped you. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 1.* You have to set the tags of your form as method="POST"

**Example**
Routing: send_my_form goes to a controller/action
Form: `<form action="<?php echo url_for('send_my_form') ?>" method="POST">`

and then in the action (send_my_form) of the controller you defined the routing:

```
$request->isMethod('post')
```

If you are not getting the method as post, try looking at the Network in your browser console and check the headers if the inputs are going as POST and not GET

Comment: Now we have changed it but same result get  var_dump($request->isMethod('post'));die;
result :- bool(false)

Comment: Did you check in your Network, when the form is submitted, the headers its sending?